# Whats wrong? SQL case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, procedure

i have this procedure and i cant see my error, someone? I want to add some text and print only the vocals.

```
create procedure sacaVocales
@vocales varchar(20)
as
begin
declare @repeticiones int = len(@vocales)
declare @contador int = 1
declare @resultado varchar(20)
declare @dato varchar(1)
while @contador<=@repeticiones
begin
select @dato = SUBSTRING(@vocales, @contador, @contador+ 1)
    case @dato
    when 'a' then @resultado = @resultado + @dato
    when 'e' then @resultado = @resultado + @dato
    when 'i' then @resultado = @resultado + @dato
    when 'o' then @resultado = @resultado + @dato
    when 'u' then @resultado = @resultado + @dato
set @contador = @contador + 1
end
print @resultado
end
```

My error is near from "case"

Comment: missing `end`..also a `,` before the `case` begins

Comment: , added! What end? Now my error is near on '='

Comment: @dato is a column alias. You can't use it in the same query, ehich you are using in `case`

Comment: @dato is a varchar from substring, the way to get all length from my text

Comment: You're missing an `END` after your final `WHEN`, before `SET @contador`

Comment: It appears that you've never accepted an answer to one of your questions. Accepting answers is part of the etiquette at StackOverflow.  See [How Does Accepting An Answer Work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of gathering vowels:

```
declare @Vocales as VarChar(20) = 'vocales';
declare @Repeticiones as Int = Len( @Vocales );
declare @Contador as Int = 1;
declare @Resultado as VarChar(20) = '';
declare @Dato as VarChar(1);

while @Contador <= @Repeticiones
  begin
  set @Dato = Substring( @Vocales, @Contador, @Contador + 1 );
  if @Dato in ( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' )
    set @Resultado += @Dato;
  set @Contador += 1;
  end;

print @Resultado;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

As mentioned in the comments by VKP, you cannot pull from the CASE statement in the same query, to get around that you can just create an additional SELECT for the CASE statement

Second, when using CASE you don't need the equal sign (=) after THEN.  "THEN" is essentially the equal sign so just put the values you want it to equal.

If you try this the query runs succesfully:

```
DECLARE @vocales VARCHAR(20) = 'vocales'
declare @repeticiones int = len(@vocales)
declare @contador int = 1
declare @resultado varchar(20)
declare @dato varchar(1)
while @contador<=@repeticiones
begin
select @dato = SUBSTRING(@vocales, @contador, @contador+1)
SELECT
    case @dato
        when 'a' then @resultado + @dato
        when 'e' then @resultado + @dato
        when 'i' then @resultado + @dato
        when 'o' then @resultado + @dato
        when 'u' then @resultado + @dato
    END
set @contador = @contador + 1
end
print @resultado
```

However, as it currently is this query will just provide a number of NULL values equal to the length of the @vocales value.  This is because the value of parameter @resultado is never declared and in your CASE statement you are adding a NULL value to a known value which will always equal NULL.

Let me know what output you are looking for and I can revise my query to help you get there.